# Is there a way to use Fastlane to deliver app to a physical device?

Tags: ios, cordova, fastlane, iosdeployment

I use Fastlane to build and deliver my apps, but still could not find a way to build and deliver the apps directly to my physical device (attached to the Mac) via command line. Currently this is the only task I need to use Xcode to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

do you now about this tool? https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy I know that this tool isn't `fastlane` but you can combine with `fastlane`. Build `*.app` from `fastlane` and upload with `ios-deploy`. (`ios-deploy` command can be inside of fastlane because you can call any script from fastlane)

I hope that my answer make sense.

Comment: Thanks Jakub for your answer. It took me some days to find out how, but finally I could make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I glad that I can help you. If my answer helped can you mark it as correct answer?